# Displaying Column names of empty cells for a given row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The basic premise is that I want to create a column that outputs the column names of the first 3-4 cells that are blank for its associated row. I have a picture of how it would work in theory. I can tell that the cells in my actual spreadsheet are truly empty since I can conditionally format them, but I have no scripting or formula skills to actually output information in a new column.

A solution for this would help out a lot of teachers and students keep better track of their progress so I really appreciate the help!

[image: Example Screenshot]

I tried using the new code there- it does display 3 column names for the first one, but when I copy that cell and select all the other cells in the column and paste it doesn't behave the same. I made a couple of different situations so hopefully that can help unravel it a bit. Should I be doing that in a different way?

[Output Test with n first empty cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqpyS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have Office 365 Excel, use TEXTJOIN as an array formula"

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2:I2="",$B$1:$I$1,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

to limit the number of returns it gets tricky:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2:INDEX(B2:I2,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(B2:I2)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:I2))+1)/(B2:I2=""),MIN(3,SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:I2 = "")))))="",$B$1:INDEX($B$1:$I$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(B2:I2)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:I2))+1)/(B2:I2=""),MIN(3,SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:I2 = ""))))),""))
```

Still an array formula.  There are two places where I put `3` which indicates the max number of blanks to return.

Comment: Wow thats awesome. And if it was a longer sheet I would just edit the I2 and $I$1 to whatever the last column is right?

Now is there anyway for it not to output every single empty cell in the row? Perhaps the first n cells? This is amazing already but figured I would ask.

Comment: @pirateyoshi yes.

Comment: Oh sorry I clicked enter too soon there I edited my post just now. :]

Comment: @pirateyoshi see edit

Comment: Thanks, I edited my main post to show a couple of different scenarios that are happening with the other rows once I paste it. I cant really figure out why it only puts out 1 column name for some, and others 2, and some 3.

Comment: @pirateyoshi see edit